# Inspect elements/text of a webpage?

Tags: java, search, image-processing

I don't want an explanation of how to do this, but rather what language would be best suited for accomplishing this task:

Say you are on a website and wanted to search for something similar to an existing image/text that you had. For instance:

---

On this website, there is the word that looks like this ***Hello***

And you had an existing display of this that looked something like this: Hello

---

What I want is to be able to scan the webpage for contents that are similar to a bit of text (this shouldn't find things based on text, but rather the actual image, like searching for identical pixels or something like that). Sort of like how Ctrl+f works, but instead of searching for text, it would use an existing image to search for a similar looking image.

What language would do this? And if you know any libraries in that language that would help in the creation of this, that would be great.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to OCR the "pictures of text" on a web page (say, headlines), and then search it for matching text?

Comment: Yes, but not just text, images also.

Comment: so are you looking to, e.g. find a picture of a tree, and match it to another (perhaps somewhat different) picture of a tree? or just text that might be in a different typeface or style?

Comment: Yeah something like the tree matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html)